# Open Apache Tomcat local access logs

Tags: python, tomcat

Please let me know if this question is published in the wrong area.

I'm trying to open the Apache Tomcat local access log files and monitor the file for a certain keyword (which I have scripted - please see below) however if anybody is familiar with Apache Tomcat, the logs rotate on a daily basis so I'm not sure where to begin in terms of allowing for this in my script. I'm also very new to Python. If anyone has any suggestions please let me know. Also, please feel free to rip this code apart :)

```
with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'X:/localhost_access_log.2020-06-11.txt')) as f:
    for character, line in enumerate(f):
        found = line.find('HTTP/1.1" 500')
        if found != -1 and found !=0:
            l.append(character)
            if (len(l) > 10):
                p.append(character)
            else:
                continue
```

if (len(p) >=1):
If this condition is true it will send me an email to inform me that I have more than 10 HTTP 500 errors in my access log

Just to reiterate the problem is trying to open a log file whose name changes on a daily basis:
"localhost_access_log.2020-06-11.txt"

This part of the text/log file always stays the same: localhost_access_log.

but the 'YYYY-MM-DD' will change daily

Appreciate any information you may have

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after an extensive investigation.

```
path = "Your path"
os.chdir(path)
files = glob.glob("localhost_access_log*.txt")
files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime,reverse=True)
files.sort(key=os.path.getctime,reverse=True)
files.append(files)
p=files[0]

with open(p) as f:
    for character, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        found = line.find('HTTP/1.1" 500')
        if found != -1 and found !=0:
            l.append(character)
            if (len(l) > 10):
                o.append(character)
            else:
                continue
```

First off you need to map a drive to the location of the log directory (SMB)
Sort the directory by modified and change date by using the Glob library. Isolate the first entry by adding it to a list. Then open that file and search for your key word. In my case 'HTTP/1.1 "500' is the keyword. Based on the result I can send a notification via SMTP to alert me.

Feel free to provide comments and opinions